# Refactoring expression - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, refactoring, expression

I have a function that gets a random number between a min and max.

I call the function on a variable as such.

```
randomPage = getRandomIntInclusive(1, 5);
```

i get to call that expression "randomPage = getRandomIntInclusive(1, 5);" several times in my code (let's say 5 to 10 times at different functions). Is there a way to refactor it further or call it in a better way?

The way i call it is like

```
function a() {
 randomPage = getRandomIntInclusive(1, 5);
}

function b() {
 randomPage = getRandomIntInclusive(1, 5);
}

function c() {
 randomPage = getRandomIntInclusive(1, 5);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you always gonna call the function with the same params ?

Comment: you will have to share the code where u r using it 4-5 times.

Comment: This question belongs to code-review site https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @gurvinder372.. thanks i will write a post on codereview.

Comment: @orangespark . i made the changes. I have added 3 functions where the code is called. Can it be refactored further?